# Adding values to dict keys and printing them in specific format

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have created a dict with key and empty values. i am trying to update the values based on the condition whether the key is divisible by any other number. i am able to get the output based on the code

```
adict = {}
for i in range (1,7):
    adict[i] = []
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        if(i%j==0):
            print ((j),end='')
```

i got the following output :11213124151236

i am looking for the desired output that updates the value for the dict : `{1:[1],2:[1,2],3:[1,3],4:[1,2,4],5:[1,5],6:[1,2,3,6]}`

Comment: `adict = {i: [j for j in range(1, i+1) if i % j == 0] for i in range(1, 7)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below,

```
adict = {}
for i in range (1,7):
    adict[i] = []

    for j in range (1,i+1):
        if(i%j == 0):
            adict[i].append(j)
print(adict)
```

Output:

```
{1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3], 4: [1, 2, 4], 5: [1, 5], 6: [1, 2, 3, 6]}
```